# UIPanGestureRecognizer detect non-movement/stillness

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using UIPanGestureRecognizer to track movement of finger. The user may pan quite fast initially but then may hold on to a point on the screen for few seconds or so without releasing the finger. I want to detect when such a premature 'end of dragging' event. I tried detecting this using velocity but it is not always reliable.

```
       let location = panGesture.location(in: selectedCell.superview)
        
        let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: selectedCell.superview)
        NSLog("Velocity, \(velocity)")
        
        switch panGesture.state {
        case .began:
            break
            
        case .changed:
            let delta = panGesture.translation(in: self)
            
            if velocity.x <= 0.05 && velocity.y <= 0.05 {
                NSLog("Velocity 0!!!!")
            }
            panGesture.setTranslation(.zero, in: self)
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is not moving the finger at all, the event won't be fired. Here's a workaround -

Once you know that the `gesture.state == .began`, Add a timer to fire every **0.1s** to check what is translation since last known point.

Even if user holds still, you will be able to check the translation and hence the velocity every **0.1s** reliably.

Do not forget to call `timer.invalidate()` in `.cancelled`, `.ended` & `.failed` states.

Comment: I tried the timer but the problem is velocity is (2.0, 0.0) or (10.0, 0.0) even though I am not moving. It's not (0.0, 0.0). Is there a reliable way to catch velocity i wonder. Also i am resetting translation to 0 in .changed so I am not sure checking translation in timer block would be reliable too.

Comment: You need to have a separate storage for `var lastKnownPoint: CGPoint` that you should not reset anywhere except in **.began** block. Now even if you reset `panGesture`'s translation to zero, it won't affect your storage. In the timer block, you can calculate distance between `lastKnownPoint` & `currentLocation` of the `panGesture` using distance formula - `sqrt(pow(x1-x2, 2) + pow(y1-y2, 2))`.

Comment: Yes, velocityInview is not updated it seems if user doesn't move the finger.